# All parameters in this create method are being inserted in the db; except for one. Is it an issue with nested form or the datatype?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, decimal, parameters, nested-form-for

I am new to ruby on rails and coding in general.
I wrote a nested form_for where the Price class belongs to an Item class.
The values :amount, :timeframe, and :item_id are to be stored through the controller. After the action ends only the :timeframe and :item_id are stored but not the :amount value.

Does this have to do with:

- The nested form?
- The datatype, and or precision & scale details for :amount?
- Could it also be an issue with my controller method?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @item, html: {multipart: true}  do |f| %>

    <div class="main-form">
        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :description %>
            <%= f.text_field :description %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :deposit %>
            <%= f.text_field :deposit %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :tags %>
            <%= f.text_field :tags %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :image  %>
            <%= f.file_field :image  %>
        </div>

        <%= fields_for :price do |f| %>
        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%=f.label :timeframe %>
            <%= select_tag(:timeframe, options_for_select([["Hour"],["Day"],["Week"]])) %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%=f.label :amount %>
            <%=f.number_field :amount %>
        </div>
        <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

This is the controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @price = Price.where(item_id: @item.id).first
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
    @price = Price.create(:timeframe => params[:timeframe], :amount => params[:amount], :item_id => @item.id)
    @price.save
      redirect_to @item, notice: "Item Successfully Added!"
    else
      flash[:message] = "Something did not validate"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, :image, :user_id, :deposit, :tags)
  end

end
```

Additional documents include the Item model and Price model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :deposit, :tags,  presence: true

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :prices, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :reviews, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :ratings, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users_that_reviewed_this, through: :reviews, source: :user
    has_many :users_that_rated_this, through: :ratings, source: :user
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :item end
```

As well as the database schema for these classes:

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "deposit"
    t.string   "type"
    t.string   "tags"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "timeframe"
    t.decimal  "amount"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is in `params[:amount]`. No params are there, it should be `params[:price][:amount]`. It will work this way!

Though the approach is not the most "conventional"
Here is the correct approach using `accepts_nested_attributes`, adding `prices_attributes` to `strong_parameters` and using

**In your model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :deposit, :tags,  presence: true

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :prices, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users_that_reviewed_this, through: :reviews, source: :user
    has_many :users_that_rated_this, through: :ratings, source: :user

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**In your controller**

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.prices.build
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item, notice: "Item Successfully Added!"
    else
      flash[:message] = "Something did not validate"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

 private
 def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, :image, :user_id, :deposit, :tags, prices_attributes: [:timeframe, :amount])
  end
```

**In your view**

```
<%= form_for @item, html: {multipart: true}  do |f| %>

    <div class="main-form">
        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :description %>
            <%= f.text_field :description %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :deposit %>
            <%= f.text_field :deposit %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :tags %>
            <%= f.text_field :tags %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%= f.label :image  %>
            <%= f.file_field :image  %>
        </div>

        <%= f.fields_for :prices, Price.new do |p| %>
        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%=p.label :timeframe %>
            <%= p.select(:timeframe, [["Hour"],["Day"],["Week"]], :prompt => 'Select') %>
        </div>

        <div class="new-item-form">
            <%=p.label :amount %>
            <%=p.number_field :amount %>
        </div>
        <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thank you @MohamedOsama this worked! The only thing I had to add was:
In the Controller
item.prices.build

In the View
f.fields_for :prices Price.new do |p|

Comment: Yes sorry you should build a price model in your controller. Also you can use 'cocoon' gem if you want to add multiple models for the association. Good luck. If the answer is correct mark it as correct haha 